# GitHub default README markup

Tags: git, github

Just a really quick question relating to GitHubs function to take a README file and display it on any repository. I know it uses [this repository to do it](https://github.com/github/markup), but was wondering if supplied without any extension (i.e. `README` not `README.markdown`) whether it does any form of formatting at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your README is just called `README`, the only thing GitHub does is turn URLs into links.