# why doesn't the image in following github repo does not show up in readme as inline image

Tags: github, markdown

I tried to present an image in my readme markdown as following:

[here trying to show images in readme on page itself](https://github.com/tomer-ben-david/akkaServlet)

however its not showing up.

i'm using the following format

```
![some alt text](raw url to image)
```

supposed to show the image?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but you should rename your file into:

```
README.md
```

That would trigger the interpretation of the [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown):

See also:

- "[Github: `README` and `README.md`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8655950/6309)".
- "[GitHub default README markup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9430425/6309)":

> When your `README` is just called `README`, **the only thing GitHub does is turn URLs into links**.

That seems consistent with what you see in your current `README` file.