# Count number of empty repositories on GitHub

Tags: github

I was just wondering if it's possible to count the total number of empty repositories on GitHub.

If not for all users, can it be done for yourself?

### Edit

I have tried the [`size:0`](https://github.com/search?q=size%3A0&ref=simplesearch) search, but it seems to return a lot of repositories which do contain data. Taking something like `size:0..1` didn't help either.

If I try searching for the keyword `empty`, but it doesn't cover all aspects.

### Update

I got a response from Brian Levine (GitHub)

> That would be an interesting statistic. We don't have a simple way to do that right now. However, you might be able to use the GitHub API to get close. You could look through public repositories and compare "pushed_at" and "created_at" dates to see if there has been any activity. Additionally, you could find repositories with a "size" of 0. There's more information on how to find this information, and much more, right here:
>
> http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? A repository with no files and no commits? I've never seen such a repository on GitHub!

Comment: @RobinGreen Yes! Repo with no files. That's very much possible. Many people create repos but never push code.

Answer (score 4):

You could:

- list [all public repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories) through the API, and,
- for each repo, check the ones with a size equals to 0.
  (The [size seems to be in KB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679592/6309))

  ```
  GET /repos/:owner/:repo
  ```

Note that an "empty" repo could still have at least one commit, when created with the default `README.md` description file.
Actually, as the [OP Aniket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887263/aniket) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889899/count-number-of-empty-repositories-on-github/19889930?noredirect=1#comment29588727_19889930):

> I explained the **meaning of empty as: 0-1 commits, max 3 files**:

```
.gitignore
README.md
LICENSE
```

(Note: [`README` is different from `README.md`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19814458/6309))

Another way is, for each repo, to [look at the number of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15919708/6309).
0 or 1 commit means probably an empty repo.

---

Update: GitHub confirms there is no current way to determine if a repo is "empty".
The closest way to do that would be:

> You could look through public repositories and compare "pushed_at" and "created_at" dates to see if there has been any activity

Comment: I have tried this, but 0kb repos also have some data. https://github.com/search?q=size%3A0&ref=simplesearch This means that GitHub doesn't repond to the 0kb query.

Comment: @Aniket yes, as I mentioned in my edited answer. I suspect a sort is in order, for you to detect "small" repos which are probably "empty" repos.

Comment: The `commit:0..1` logic seems to make sense, but GitHub doesn't accept a parameter like that.

Comment: @Aniket yes, I agree, and the API only reflects the commits from the last n days, so it isn't even valid for *all* repo. I would still sort repos by size.

Comment: I think I should get in touch with GitHub about this, if it's even possible.

Comment: @Aniket I fully agree.

Comment: Sent the query. Will update here after I get a response. I explained the meaning of empty as: 0-1 commits, max 3 files - `.gitignore`, `README`, `LICENSE`

Comment: @Aniket Great! I have included your definition of "empty" repo in my answer, for more visibility.

Comment: @Aniket interesting. Thank you for the update (and thanks to GitHub support). I have added the relevant section in the answer.

Comment: I will try working with the idea they gave me and get back to you if I find that method workable.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a repository is empty, look to see if it has any commits.

https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits?per_page=1

An empty repository will have a non-successful HTTP status and the content...

```
{
  "message": "Git Repository is empty.",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

If it doesn't exist, you'll get a 404 and...

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

If it does exist, you'll get an HTTP 200 and one commit.

Answer (score 2):

Using the attribute "size" from the API will not help as mentioned by other posters here.

An example is this repository:
https://api.github.com/repos/errfree/test

If you note, it displays the size as 48 despite being empty.

**Disclaimer**: This approach is a hack. It is not efficient nor officially supported by GitHub, but works good enough for me.

Basically, I download the Zip version of the repository. When the repository is empty then it will not return a zip file but provides as result an HTML page saying "This repository is empty.".

After downloading a zip file, I verify if the size is smaller than 30Kb and if this is the case, I look inside the file contents for the string "This repository is empty." to confirm that a given repository is empty.

Here is a practical example of direct zip download that on this case will display an empty page:
https://github.com/errfree/test/zipball/master/

My pseudo-code in Java:

```
        // we might have reached an empty repository
        if(fileZip.length() < 30000){
            // read the contents
            final String content = utils.files.readAsString(fileZip);
            // is this an HTML file with the repository empty message?
            if(content.contains("This repository is empty.")){
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.